# Ediciones de etiquetas

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

A veces cuando voy a editar una etiqueta, me sale este texto en la página de edición de la etiqueta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven dice que la etiqueta **no tiene aún orientación de uso**, esta etiqueta que uso de ejemplo es **backend** y está presente en 163 preguntas (cifra que no es despreciable) y así hay otras tantas. Yo me pregunto entonces cuando una etiqueta está lista para que se pueda escribir su significado y que criterios hay que tener en cuenta para que una etiqueta ya esté lista para poder escribir su significado.

Answer (score 3):

Eso es porque nadie le ha puesto una orientación de uso, para hacerlo solo hay que dar clic en el simbolito de pregunta:

[image: Sitio para editar la información de etiqueta]

y le das clic al botón azul que dice **Proponer información de etiqueta**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y adentro solo pones la información que creas que es la que mejor define la etiqueta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tienes menos de 20 000 de reputación, tienes que esperar a que la revisen y aprueben.

Comment: El boton azul no me sale, algo esta faltando, pq ya he editado otras, pero hay otras q no puedo editar

Comment: Tambien puedes hacerlo buscando en el apartado de etiquetas, la etiqueta y le das clic, aparecerá [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backed) ahí aparecerá un link en la parte superior que dice, [ayúdanos a crearla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/1270) y de esa manera alternativa tambien puedes añadir información sobre esa etiqueta.

Comment: Todo eso yo lo se, yo he editado ya varias etiquetas, pero parece que no todas son editables hasta que se cumpla con algo y ese algo es lo q no se q es

Comment: Mmm pues, que raro, desde el link que comente que dice ayudanos a crearla no te deja tampoco?

Comment: No, hay etiquetas q no se dejan editar, quizá algún moderador sepa la respuesta, @gbianchi ven a mi rescate :)

Comment: Creo que ya se lo que ocurre: Para poder editar una etiqueta debes esperar a que tus ediciones de etiqueta anteriores sean aprobadas

Comment: Mmm no, probé poniéndole información a la etiqueta background y me deja añadir información a otras etiquetas, pero acabo de ver y a mi tampoco me deja editar la etiqueta backend, prueba editar la etiqueta background y si no te deja entonces el problema es que alguien ya a añadido información a esa etiqueta y esta en revision

Comment: Se me ocurre que una etiqueta no puede editarse mientras no se haya hecho la revisión a una edición previa de ella (así como sucede con las preguntas y respuestas). Gracias @Juantro17 por dar una etiqueta de ejemplo ;)

Comment: @padaleiana a ti te deja editar la información de la etiqueta background?

Comment: No, y nunca la edité. Por eso asumo que es lo que mencioné en el comentario anterior.

Comment: Ahhh ok, si debe ser eso, ojalá algún moderador pudiera confirmar